# Shipping address edit content not loading in fields Magento 2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, shipping-address

While clicking the edit button in shipping address on the one-page checkout Magento 2, field values are not loading in the popup. Please help me.
[image]

Comment: Please check in local storage of browser. Edit form data is stored in "shippingAddressFromData" json format on key press data binding.

Comment: while clicking on edit pop up enabled without field values, and save as new address. How to update thode address

Comment: how to load popup form with existing address?